# React Flow using ref and accessing the HTMLElement

Tags: reactjs, lambda, flowtype

Im adding flow to my React project. I followed the instructions in the flow react ref section.

my problem is that Im using the ref object in multiple positions so if I define it as optional I get an error accessing it, otherwise I get an error from the ref itself because its initially null.

is there a solution where I dont need to check each time I want to use the ref? can I tell flow to not run checks on refs?

here is a short snippet to explain what Im doing:

```
class AudioPlayer extends Component<Props> {
  player: ?HTMLAudioElement;

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.duration && this.player.currentTime >= nextProps.duration) {
      this.reset();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { src } = this.props;

    return (
      <audio
        className="track-audio"
        ref={audio => (this.player = audio)}
        loop
        onTimeUpdate={this.handleTimeUpdate}
        onLoadedMetadata={this.handleLoadMetadata}
      >
        <source src={src} />
      </audio>
    );
  }
}
```

considering I dont want to remove the ref, is there an easy solution apart of checking if `!isEmpty(this.player)` wherever I need it?

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/refs/) describe why you should use an optional regardless. You can also define it like below (no real advantage unless you find it easier to understand at a glance):

```
class AudioPlayer extends Component<Props> {
  player: ?React.ElementRef<'audio'>;

  // ...rest
}
```

If you find that to be annoying (I completely understand, believe me), you could do a few different things (I'll only list the ones I can think of off the top of my head):

1. Pass the function as a callback that checks (not super elegant, but it gets the job done)

   ```
   class AudioPlayer extends Component<Props> {
     checkForPlayer(callback) {
       if (this.player) {
         return callback()
       }
     }

     componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
       this.checkForPlayer(() => {
         if (nextProps.duration && this.player.currentTime >= nextProps.duration) {
           this.reset();
         }
       })
     }
   }
   ```
2. You could do something similar, but kind of as a decorator (I personally think this is harder to read in general, but it is an option)

   ```
   class AudioPlayer extends Component<Props> {
     checkForPlayer(callback) {
       return (...args) => 
         if (this.player) {
           return callback(...args)
         }
       }
     }

     componentWillUpdate: this.checkForPlayer(nextProps => {
       if (nextProps.duration && this.player.currentTime >= nextProps.duration) {
         this.reset();
       }
     })
   }
   ```
3. You could use a utility function similar to (or exactly) [`lodash.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) whenever you are accessing properties on `this.player` (`get(this.player, 'currentTime')`). Unless you think you'll see big benefits from the previous options, I would probably stick with something like this. You'll get used to the syntax pretty quickly and it doesn't require a lot of extra work. You could even do something like this (this was pretty much an afterthought after looking over my answer. It's probably not better than using a common utility function):

   ```
   class AudioPlayer extends Component<Props> {
     playerProp(prop) {
       return this.player ? this.player[prop] : null
     }

     componentWillUpdate: this.checkForPlayer(nextProps => {
       if (nextProps.duration && this.playerProp('currentTime') >= nextProps.duration) {
         this.reset();
       }
     })
   }
   ```

Comment: Defining it as the ElementRef. Would it solve anything? Or is it just another way of defining the HTMLAudioElement?

Comment: @Jony-Y Just another way of defining it.